# Formula in Flow - send email if Status hasn't changed in the past 5 days

Tags: visual-workflow, formula, administration

I'm new to Flow. I've created the Scheduled Trigger Flow on my CustomObject.
I created a Formula Resource: StatusNotChanged
NOT((ISCHANGED({!$Record.Status__c}))
I've added a Decision that checks StatusNotChanged is True

In the formula, how do I add check for "Status has not changed in 5 days"?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure your existing formula makes sense. Since this is a *scheduled* flow, when it runs there's no context of whether something changed or not as the record hasn't undergone an update or anything. It's just a scheduled action (query) on records in your instance.

`ISCHANGED()` is useful in *record-triggered* flows where the records in the transaction have had an update and can compare the prior value with the current value.

Now, to your specific question, there's *many ways* to do this.

Going off using a scheduled flow, I'd suggest creating an extra custom field titled `Last Status Changed Date` on the object.

This would require you to create a separate flow/trigger/automation for the object to stamp this custom date field whenever the Status changes.

Then, in this flow you could add a formula to check how many days the Status has been unchanged

`{!$Flow.CurrentDate} - {!Record.Last_Status_Changed_Date__c} > 5`.

Answer (score 1):

Given a field `CustomObject__c.LastStatusChange__c` that is set by a trigger or point-and-click automation (not a formula field)

Then you can create a Record-triggered Flow with Scheduled Paths

Here's a screen shot from my org that did something similar with stale `Opportunity.StageName` changes:

[image]

A Paused Flow Interview is created as soon as `CustomObject__c.LastStatusChange__c` is set (in your case, 5 days hence)

If the value of `CustomObject__c.LastStatusChange__c` changes before the 5 days are up, the Paused Flow Interview is changed to be 5 days hence from the new value.

Otherwise, the paused flow interview starts and executes the elements in the scheduled *path*